# Chrome extension fake users

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webstore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apparent fake installs of Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552237/apparent-fake-installs-of-chrome-extension)

I really hope that someone can help us because we are really frustrated with this:

We developed a new Chrome extension and published it in the web store about 2 weeks ago.

When adding our extension to Chrome the extension communicates with our API and get a unique User_ID for each new user.

On our database we have a table of users with the User_ID & IP.

The weird part:
We see about 10-15 new users in that table every day - all with different IPs but there aren't any new users according to the chrome webstore (also these users are not active after the installation).

Our guess is that a robot might be "installing" our extension - but 10-15 every day from different IPs sounds extra weird!

Can someone please help?

Comment: Did you find out whose IP are those? Perhaps Google Web Store robots are testing your extension!  In January 2013 a new Chrome extension attack showed up, may be now they are extra careful.

Comment: I send google a question about it but haven't received any reply. some of these IP are from Bangladesh and some from the states - about 100 different c-class IPs - I doubt it is google.... smells like spammers..